# Валидация пары логин/пароль. Как решить?

Tags: php

Логин/пароль админа, хранятся в бд, в таблице `admin`. Есть скрипт валидации, который проверяет их на корректность при входе в «админку». Не соображу, как передать данные из бд и предоставить для проверки валидатору. Вот такой скрипт:

```
public function loginValidate()
{
    $params = [
        'login' => $admin['login'],
        'password' => $admin['password'],
    ];

    $admin = $this->db->all('SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE login = :login AND password = :password', $params);
    
    /*Это я глядел чего в переменных хранится
    echo 'POST '; print_r($_POST);
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'admin '; print_r($admin);
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'admin '; print_r($admin['login']);
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'admin '; print_r($admin['password']);
    echo '<br />';*/

    if ($admin['login'] != $_POST['login'] or $admin['password'] != $_POST['password']) {
        $this->error = 'Login incorrect!';
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Такой вот вывод:

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: admin in /models/AdminModel.php on line 28
 Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /models/AdminModel.php on line 28
 Notice: Undefined variable: admin in /models/AdminModel.php on line 29
 Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null /home/max/www/test/application/models/AdminModel.php on line 29
 Notice: Undefined index: login in /models/AdminModel.php on line 42
 {"status":"error","message":"Login incorrect!"}
```

Это результат при нарочито некорректных введённых логине/пароле.

Вопрос решил так:

```
public function loginValidate()
{
    $password = $this->db->col('SELECT * FROM `admin`');
    
    if (!password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
        $this->error = 'Login incorrect!';
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: А вверху метода откуда берутся `'login' => $admin['login'], 'password' => $admin['password']` в массиве `$params`? Ведь переменная $admin в этот момент не определена, вот Вам и вываливает ошибки. По крайней мере первых 4. Ну и последняя ошибка уже относится непосредственно к тому что Вы получаете при помощи Вашего SQL запроса.

Comment: А для чего вам вообще получать пароль пользователя из базы данных? Это лишнее. Вы отправляете запрос в БД с поиском по collum логина и пароля, если совпадение есть, то выводите данные пользователя для аунтефикации.

Comment: Fox, а там всего один пользователь — админ, по этому совпадения искать нет смысла. Я сократил таблицу вообще до единственного столбца с хешем пароля и валидатор просто сравнивает с ним то, что вводится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения многих задач бывает полезно написать алгоритм в псевдокоде или хотя бы просто списком:

```
- получить логин, переданный пользователем
- выбрать из бд запись, соответствующую этому логину (where login = :login)
- если запись не найдена, то пользователь ввёл неверный логин
- иначе получить пароль, переданный пользователем, и сравнить его с паролем полученным из бд
- если пароли совпадают, то это админ
- иначе пользователь ввёл неверный пароль
```

Как видите, всё просто и логично. Осталось только реализовать это. Думаю вы справитесь.

Теперь другой момент. Хранить пароль в бд небезопасно. Это как записвывать пароль на бумажке.
Если кто-нибудь получит доступ к базе, то узнает пароли и сможет ими незаметно пользоваться.
Лучше хранить в базе [хэши](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) от паролей.

Для вычисления хэша пароля в php есть специальная функция [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php).
Перед сохранением пароля в бд применяйте к паролю password_hash, а при проверке пароля применяйте [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php).

```
$admin = $this->db->all(...);
...
$password = $_POST['password']?? '';
if (password_verify($password, $admin['password'])) {
    // пользователь ввёл верный пароль
}
```